# Excel - how to calculate sum of multiple rows into different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't know how to title this. However the question is similar but the output I need is different. Hopefully screen shot will show more clarity.

With formula showing:

[image: with formula showing]

What I'm trying to do and hopefully is able to do is, I need to do all those sum's and for the answers to be in the cells shown in total 1 and total 2. For those totals I did it manually, is there a way to do it automatically?

When I do subtotal for instance, I can do each block of sums, but I get the total answer for the whole table and not for each section as shown in the image. When I drag the sum down, I have to delete every other row. Is there a cleaner way?

Without formula showing:

[image: without formula showing]

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't really understand what you are accomplishing with the formula in column E, this should solve your problem:

In Column E:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,$C2,"")
```

In Column F:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,SUM(D2,D3),"")
```

This will only populate on the even numbered rows.

Comment: thank you that worked perfect, i missed the sum part in the collum E thats my bad thank you for pointing it out. I was trying to experiment with the $ in the formular to see if i had any luck. Your column F fomular worked for both instances. :)

Comment: if some of the rows were 3 rows down rather all being two, would there still be a way of doing it

Comment: @bobssagetto if they are randomly 2 or 3 then no.  You would need to have an additional column to indicate the "groupings" and use that to determine if you should SUM the rows or now.

Answer (score 1):

Select the block `E2:F3` (4 cells) and drag down the small green box at the right bottom corner of `F3`. This will copy the block through all the lines.

**(Note: you should select two lines to copy the pattern)**

Comment: that populates the rows which are blank in the total column, thats what i mentioned in the question

Comment: Once again, if you select **two** rows, one of which is empty and drag down, it will populate with the pattern you've selected, namely, with one line filled and one line empty. Just try and see the result. If you see the other result, please show how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `E2` : `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(),SUM(C2:C3)),"")`
You can drag it down and to column F.

Or dynamically:
`=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(),SUM(INDEX($A:$D,ROW(),COLUMN()-2):INDEX($A:$D,ROW()+1,COLUMN()-2))),"")`